# How to access Many-to-Many field data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Work_Music(MPTTModel, Work):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)   
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    tonality = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class WorkCast(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work'), related_name='workcast', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Cast, verbose_name=_('cast'), related_name='workcast', blank=True)
    order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Cast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

In view.py, I send the following in template context:

```
work_cast = WorkCast.objects.get(work=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

How do I display in the template,

```
 Cast #1, Cast #2, Cast #3, Cast #4
```

How to I grab all of the cast members? Is it?

```
work.cast.cast.all()
```

doesn't yield any output.

How do I display it as a list with commas in between?

Comment: did you try `prefetch_related` ?
you can  go through this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Simply `work.cast.all()` will work, rather than `work.cast.cast.all()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are sending a context variable to your template called "work_cast" and this variable references one `WorkCast` instance.

In the django template language do not use the `()` so grabbing all the Cast members of that one `WorkCast` instance would be

```
work_cast.cast.all
```

You can interate through the instances as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for cast in work_cast.cast.all %}
    {{ cast }}
    {% if not forloop.last %}
    , 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the loops the django template language add some extra variable which you can use. In this case we use it to avoid putting a comma after the last entry of your list.